# Automatically changing user role upon purchase in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I would like to make a members only section for WooCommerce customers who have made completed purchases, by assigning them a new role as the default for all registered users are "customer".

I've stumbled across some code which can solve this, however with over 200 products in store, it would be a hassle to list all the products individually.

Is there anyway to give a customer who makes ANY purchase a new role?

This is the original code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase' );

function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

// get order object and items
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $product_id = 56; // that's a specific product ID

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Remove old role
            $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

            // Add new role
            $user->add_role( 'editor' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use the following instead, which will change the user role when a customer make a successful purchase (paid order):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_role_on_purchase', 10, 2 );
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {
    $user = $order->get_user(); // Get the WP_User Object

    // Check for "customer" user roles only
    if( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && in_array( 'customer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove WooCommerce "customer" role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add new role
        $user->add_role( 'editor' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Note:** The `WC_Order` Object Is already an existing argument for that hooked function *(missing from your code).*

---

#### Addition: To remove all previous roles and assign a new role

This is possible using just the [`WP_User` `set_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/set_role/) method, so in the code, replace:

```
// Remove WooCommerce "customer" role
$user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

// Add new role
$user->add_role( 'editor' );
```

by:

```
// Reset user roles and set a new one
$user->set_role( 'editor' );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much. For the "  $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); " , is there a way to remove ANY existing role and replace it with the new role? I've tried to do it by slowly listing all the roles, but it doesnt seem like very efficient or clean code